# Software claims and infringement

Tags: software

In a software patent, typically three kinds of claims expressing almost the same idea are listed, namely system claim, method claim, and media claim.

In my interpretation, the system claim and method claim have different effect in terms of type of infringement, as described below.

The list below shows relations as:

Cause -> Type of infringement.

1.System claim
 (1) Using the program -> direct infringement (using the system)
 (2) Installing the program  -> direct infringement (making the system)
 (3) Selling the program  ->  indirect infringement (inducing installing)

2.Method claim
 (1) Using the program -> direct infringement (using the method)
 (2) Installing the program  -> indirect infringement (inducing using it)
 (3) Selling the program  ->  indirect infringement  (inducing installing)

I want to make sure especially that the method claim is effective  to selling progrrams via downloading through internet.

Are those relations listed above correct?